# how to set Default Or Selected value in dropdownlistfor in asp.net MVC 4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
  public static IList<MyTestStatus> CreateMyTestStatusList()
                    {
                        List<MyTestStatus> status = new List<MyTestStatus>();
                        status.Add(new MyTestStatus() { Name = "1" });
                        status.Add(new MyTestStatus() { Name = "2" });
                        status.Add(new MyTestStatus() { Name = "3" });
                        status.Add(new MyTestStatus() { Name = "4" });
                        return status.ToList();
                    }
```

---

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyTestStatus, new SelectList(Model._MyTestViewModel.MyTestStatus), "Select.....", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

---

i have this code for dropdownlistfor i want the selected value by default to be "4" or the selected value which the user select,i used jQuery

---

```
$("#MyTestStatus").val("4");
```

---

when the page load is displaying "4" as i want,but in update the value will always display as "4" even if select a different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyTestStatus, new SelectList(Model._MyTestViewModel.MyTestStatus,"Name","Name","4"), "Select.....", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Finally..this is working fine..thank you

Comment: Sorry to be harsh but this is nonsense. Your property `MyTestStatus` is `IList<MyTestStatus>` and you cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects. You need a property to bind to (say) `public int SelectedStatus { get; set; }` and then you set the value of `SelectedStatus` in the controller before you pass it to the view, and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStatus, new SelectList(Model._MyTestViewModel.MyTestStatus,"Name","Name"), "Select.....", new { @class = "form-control"})`

Answer (score 0):

You should set your defaults to `model.MyTestStatus` model property. That's from where `DropDownListFor` helper get selected value.

Just populate this property in your controller.

Comment: Still Not Working,in my view i was trying to check if nothing selected 
'@if (Model.MyTestStatus!=null)
{
@Model.MyTestStatus
}
else
{
@
}'

Comment: @Mhmd please add your controller and more View code to question

Answer (score 0):

Since you are binding it a property using the [`DropDownFor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx) helper method, it will automatically map it to the `MyTestStatus` property on your Model. If this isn't being set properly, you could consider setting it when building your Model initially.

The [SelectList class does support a constructor for it's default selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.), but it will likely be overridden if a value is present on your Model :

```
new SelectList(Model._MyTestViewModel.MyTestStatus,"4")
```

Alternatively, you could use the `DropDown()` helper (instead of the model-bound `DropDownFor()` one) which would ignore the Model value and just use your selection :

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyTestStatus", new SelectList(Model._MyTestViewModel.MyTestStatus,"4"), "Select.....", new { @class = "form-control"})
```